# How do I parse Norway currency

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

How do I parse Norwegian currency (kr) to decimal?

I am trying to parse these:

```
477,60
2.320,00
```

This code doesn't work, and throws a decimal parse exception even though I have specified Norway as the culture for parsing.

```
Convert.ToDecimal("2.320,00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nb-NO"))
```

Comment: Norwegian is either "nb-NO" or "nn-NO", does this work if you use "nn-NO"?

Comment: @PeteStensønes no it will not work with other culture too, both of them doesn't have NumberGroupSeparator defined.

Comment: Just to make sure: is that actually the Norwegian way of formatting currencies? The thousands separator in glibc is a non-breaking space, and this is backed up by many sites (one example us http://mylittlenorway.com/2009/11/crosses-commas-and-great-divides/), but not being Norwegian myself I cannot be sure. It matters because it affects how you should solve the problem. If this is actually a custom format, then custom code at the time of parsing makes sense. If this is standard in some part of Norway, then modifying the culture info and using that throughout your application makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So Norway culture doesn't have define `NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator`, because of that you receive this exception. So you need to define them:

```
CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nb-NO");
var numberFormat = info.NumberFormat;
numberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
numberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";//this if you are using currency
numberFormat.PercentGroupSeparator = ".";//this for percentages
```

After that try to use `decimal.TryParse` method:

```
decimal result = 0;
decimal.TryParse("2.320,00", NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint|NumberStyles.AllowThousands, info, out result);
```

Here [**Full Example**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CUwj0o)